# Форматировать данные в Excel как таблицу

Tags: c#, excel

Работаю с Excel на c#. Задаю имена столбцов, вывожу данные. Хочу выделить весь диапазон и нажать "форматировать как таблицу". Выделить диапазон ячеек могу, а вот как отформатировать данные, не нашел.

Comment: Очевидно через настройку свойств. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=excel-pia тут список свойств для диапазона ячеек, настраивайте как нравится. Если форматирование колонок должно отличаться, форматируйте колонки по одной. То же и для отдельных ячеек, если какие-то из них нужно форматировать особым образом.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Excel.Range rng;
 Excel.Range cell1 = MySheet.Cells[1, 1];
 Excel.Range cell2 = MySheet.Cells[MySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, MySheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count];
 rng = (Excel.Range)MySheet.get_Range(cell1, cell2);
 rng.Select();
 rng.Worksheet.ListObjects.AddEx(SourceType: Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, Source: rng, XlListObjectHasHeaders: Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);
```

Разобрался с проблемой, код оставлю здесь на всякий случай, так как свойств и методов у объекта Range очень много.